# Generate Authentication code with random number in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I am working on project where I have to authenticate user email. For this I am generating random number and send it to user email address (just like facebook authentication) and store it in session. After 5 minutes this code is expire. Is it good practice or generating authentication code with random numbers? If not then what is good practice of generating authentication code in asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it good practice or generating authentication code with random
>   numbers?

It should be fine if you are using some strong algorithm to generate your random number. I suggest use **`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`** for generating your random number.

More details on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)

Using session for storing the generated number is not a good idea, you can end up with following issue.

- May create problem if your application is load balanced/web farm environment (When you are using inProc session state)
- Assume that if by any chance your application crashes/restarted, your
  session data will be lost.
- User have to verify from the same session, he can't verify from a
  different browser/system.

Try to store the numbers in database by implementing some strong hashing algorithm.